# Why do two Ubuntu systems in the same network behave differently in DNS resolution?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, dns, ip

I have two systems, both running Ubuntu 12.04, which are within the same network (connected by hubs without routing logic). Both systems are configured quite similar, but not identical. In particular, the command `route` gives the identical results on both system.

Within the network a windows server is operating by a name `winshared`. One Linux system work resolving the IP:

```
> nslookup winshared
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Name:   winshared.somepc.xx
Address: 172.16.0.110
```

while the other Linux system fails with

```
> nslookup winshared
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Why do I see the difference in DNS resolution on both systems? And how to fix it?

Additional remarks:

- The content of `/etc/resolv.conf` is identical on both systems with the content:

  ```
  nameserver 127.0.0.1
  ```

Comment: Do you have multiple DNS nameservers? What do you see in /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Those files were different, I made them identical (on the second system I added a line like `search winshared.de`). But still the name could not be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this problem is starting from the entries in `/etc/resolv.conf`. The content is identical, and the given IP address `127.0.0.1` refers to the system itself.

The next hint comes from the output of `nslookup`: It shows, the address of `winshared` is being resolved by a process listening on port 53. Using `sudo netstat -nlp` on the working  system reveals one process `dnsmasq` listening on this port. The other system, however, has a second process, `named`, listening on this port. `named` is a DNS server and thus probably responsible for the mess of not able to resolve a name.

[As explained](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162371/what-is-the-named-daemon-and-why-is-it-running) this service can be stopped by uninstalling `bind9`, after which the DNS service is stopped on the faulty system, and both systems only have a process `dnsmasq` running on port 53, which is a leightweight forwarding service for DNS requests.

Afterwards, the name `winshared` can be resolved on both systems.

Answer (score 0):

Typically servers behave differently because they're configured differently ;)

DNS servers are either set by DHCP or configured manually in the `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

Static entries for certain hostnames/ip-addresses may exist in `/etc/hosts`.

The `/etc/nsswitch.conf` may instruct the resolvers to give different precendence to sources such as local files / NIS / LDAP or DNS

Comment: And how can I fix my problem? As far as I know, both systems use static entries. The content of `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is also identical, only `/etc/hosts` differ in one additional line on the second system: `127.0.1.1    PC-Test` for unknown reasons.

Comment: The error message in your post is indicative that other server can't connect to the DNS servers which you have configured. Is /etc/resolv.conf really correct & correctly formatted? Can you ping those DNS servers? And lastly, nslookup always queries DNS and does **not** show /etc/hosts entries, while `ping` fi will be able to use entries from the hosts file.

Comment: As `nslookup` on the first system works, I assume `/etc/resolv.conf` is really correct and correctly formatted on the first system. The md5sums of the file `/etc/resolv.conf` are identical on both systems, so I can assume this file is also correct and correctly formatted on the second system.

Comment: Then it's time for the default excuse for a sysadmin, blame the network! Can you ping the ip-address of your nameserver(s) from both servers?

Comment: Yes, the IP address is fine in both cases.

Comment: does pointing nslookup directly at the ip-address of the nameserver(s) work as expected? `nslookup hostname - <ip-address-of-nameserver>`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the file /etc/resolv.conf is generated by the packet resolvconf.

Are you using static or Dynamic network configuration?

Have a look at the differents files in /etc/resolvconf/
and /etc/networks/interfaces.

Or if installed, use network-manager.